# AttributeError: Did you call find_all() when you meant to call find()?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, jupyter

> I am typing in the cell in following text that was shown error but same text typed in the notepad and copy, paste that is correct. Why?

```
table = soup.find_all('table')`
table.find_all('tr')

Return: AttributeError: ResultSet object has no attribute 'find_all'. You're probably treating a list of elements like a single element. Did you call find_all() when you meant to call find()?

table = soup.find_all('table')
table.find_all('tr')
Return: Correct [enter image description here][1]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tou have to use like this way

```
table = soup.find('table')
table.find_all('tr')
```